# Initial guess and resnorm Issue in Matlab curve fitting

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, differential-equations, estimation, non-linear-regression

I am fitting data to a system of non linear ODEs to estimate model parameters using Matlab `lsqcurvefit`.
In this fitting the fit depends so much on the initial guesses that I use for the `lsqcurvefit` .
For example, if I use `x0=5` as a initial guess I will get residual norm of 30, where as if I choose `x0=5.2` I get  a residual norm of 1.5.
1) What does residual norm (`resnorm`) in Matlab represent? is it the sum of the squared errors? Is there a way to decide what range of value for `resnorm` is acceptable.

2) When the fit depends so much on initial guess, is there a way to deal with these problems? How would I know whether a better fit can be obtained from a different initial guess?

3) In using `lsqcurvefit` is it required to check whether the residuals are normally distributed?

Comment: For the first question: `resnorm` is indeed `sum((y_measured-y_calculated).^2)`. So resnorm in itself is not really useful, you can divide resorm by your number of measured point to get the average error. In my opinion there is not a good or a bad `resnorm` it all depend on the needed precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lsqcurvefit` fits your data in the least squares sense. Thus it all comes down to the minimisation, and as your data is non-linear, you do not have any guarantee, that this is the global minimum nor that it is unique.

E.g. Consider the function sin(x), which x-value minimises this function, well all x=2*pi*n + 3/2*pi for n=0,1,2,... but your numerical method can only return one solution, which will then depend on your initial guess.

To further elaborate on the problem. The simplest (in my opinion) minimisation algorithm is known as the steepest descent. it uses the idea, known from calculus, that the steepest descent is in the direction of the minus the gradient. Thus it finds the gradient in the suggested point takes a step in negative that direction (scaled by some stepsize) and continues to do this until the step/derivative is significantly small.

However, even if you consider the function cos(3 pi x)/x from 0.5 to infinity, which does have a unique global minima in 1, you only find it if your guess lies in between 0.7 and 1.3 (or so). All other guesses will find their respective local minima.

With this we can answer your questions:

1) `resnorm` is the 2-norm of the residuals. What would it mean that specific norm would be acceptable? The algorithm is looking for a minimum, if you already are at a minimum, what would it mean to continue the search?

2) Not in an (pseudo) exact sense. What is typically done is to either use your knowledge to come up with a sensible initial guess. If this is not possible, you simply have to repeatedly make random initial guesses and then keep the best.

3) Depends on what you want to do, if you want to make statistical tests, which depends on the residuals being normally distributed, then YES. If you are solely interested in fitting the function with the lowest residual norm, then NO.

Comment: I use the genetic algorithm Differential Evolution to determine inital parameter estimates and have found excellent results as compared to purely random guesses.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thanks. Do you have a reference that I can use to learn on Differential evolution

Comment: I do not use matlab, however a google search turned up matlab source code, matlab examples, etc.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Of course it does. Using your knowledge to come up with initial conditions is typically better than randomly guessing. But it still does not guarantee a unique solution, nor that it is the best.

Comment: Agreed. To my knowledge no technique for non-linear optimization has yet been discovered that yields such a guaranteed solution.